# Retrieve all datas along with related data from another table - mysql, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

please find me a solution on this. I have two tables

table 1: room_rate

table 2: special_offer

here is my room_rate table

```
   room id    room_name    rate_starts   rate_ends    single_room   double_room
   1          standard     2014-01-01    2014-02-28   150           200
   1          standard     2014-03-01    2014-03-05   200           250
   1          standard     2014-03-06    2014-03-31   300           350
   2          Garden Villa 2014-01-01    2014-02-28   300           400
```

here is my special_offer table

```
   room id freenight_name   freenight_starts freenight_ends min_stay  freenights_given
   1       stay 7 pay 5     2014-02-10       2014-03-11     7         2
```

what i want to do is display All the rooms and if there is a special offer i want to display the rooms along with related special offer. So for example my search is between lets say from 2014-01-10 to 2014-01-17 i must get something like this

Standard room - Stay 7 pay

Garden villa

Standard room is displayed with special offer because on special_offer table there is special offer for standard room. However Garden villa is not having any special special offer, that's why garden villa is displayed without any special offer... I guess this would be simple.. Am using PHP, Mysql

here is my CODE

```
    SELECT *
                FROM rooms_rate AS rmrt
                LEFT JOIN special_offer
                ON rmrt.room_id = spof.room_id
                WHERE
                rmrt.hotel_id = '$hotel_id'
```

Comment: You are right. It is simple. Why not try to make an attempt and ask specific questions on any problems you may encounter? As it reads right now, you are basically asking for someone to make this effort for you.

Comment: Am really confused now.. Just help me with this..

Comment: @user2981233 you need to show some initiative on your end. SO is not a free software development service. Lots of people here who love to help learning developers, but for the most part, we want to help you learn how to fish, so to speak.  You are simply asking for a fish.

Comment: i have shown you my query above.. but its returning only the room with special offer.

Comment: please give me a hint on what to correct on my code in order to achieve my goal.

Comment: @Undefined_variable you are a good hint giver.. i Have solved my problem and edited with correct code above.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT *
            FROM rooms_rate AS rmrt
            LEFT JOIN special_offer
            ON rmrt.room_id = spof.room_id
            WHERE
            rmrt.hotel_id = '$hotel_id'
```

this query gives what i need.. it displays all the records from room_rate table and only the matched records from special offer table based on room_id